# Complex/Orchestrated CD with AWS CodePipeline or others

Tags: circleci, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codepipeline, codeship

Building a AWS serverless solution (lambda, s3, cloudformation etc) I need an automated build solution. The application should be stored in a Git repository (pref. Bitbucket or Codecommit). I looked at BitBucket pipelines, AWS CodePipeline, CodeDeploy , hosted CI/CD solutions but it seems that all of these do something static as in receiving a dumb signal that something changed to rebuild the whole environment.... like it is 1 app, not a distributed application.

I want to define **ordered** steps of what to do depending on the **filetype** per change.

E.g. 
1. every **updated** .js file containing lambda code should first be used to update the existing lambda
2. after that, every new or changed cloudformation file/stack shoud be used to update or create existing ones, there may be a needed order (importing values from each other)
3. after that, code for **new** lambda's in .js files should be used to update the created lambda's (prev step) code.

Non updated resources should NOT be updated or recreated!
It seems that my pipelines should be ordered AND have the ability to filter input (e.g. only .js files from a certain path) and receive as input also what the name of the changed resource(s) is(are).

I dont seem to find this functionality withing AWS or hosted git solutions like BitBucket or CI/CD pipelines like CircleCI or Codeship, aws CodePipeline, CodeDeploy etc.

How come? Doesn't anyone need this? Seems like a basic requirement in my eyes....

Answer (score 1):

I looked again at available AWS tooling and got to the following conclusion:

1. When coupling CodePipeline to CodeCommit repositry, every commit puts a whole package of the repositry on S3 as input for CodeCommit. So not only the changes but everything.
2. In CodePipeline there is the orchestration functionality i was looking for. You can have actions for every component like create-change-set for SAM component and execute-chage-set etc and have control over the order of all.
   But:

   - Since all code is given as input I assume all actions in CodeCommit will be triggered even for a small change in code which does not affect 99% of the resources. Underwater SAM or CF will determine themself what did or did not change. But it is not very efficient. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316886/does-aws-sam-codepipelines-do-whole-rebuild-per-commit).
   - I cannot see in the pipeline overview which one was run the last time and its status...
   - I cannot temporary disable a pipeline or trigger with custom input

In the end I think to make a main pipeline with custom lambda code determining what actually changed using CodeCommit API  and splitting all actions in sub pipelines. From the main pipeline I will push their needed input to S3 and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

(i'm not allow to comment, so i'll try and provide an answer instead - probably not the one you were hoping for :) )

There is definitely a need and at Codeship we're looking into how best to support FaaS/Serverless workflows. It's been a bit of a moving target over the last years, but more common practices etc. are starting to emerge/mature to a point where it makes more sense to start codifying them.

For now, it seems most people working in this space have resorted to scripting (either the Serverless framework, or directly against the FaaS providers) but everyone's struggling with the issue of just deploying what's changes vs. deploying everything as you point to. Adding further complexity with sequencing is obviously just making things harder.

Most services (Codeship included) will allow you some form of sequenced/stepped approach to deploying, but you'll have to do all the heavy lifting of working out what has changed etc.

As to your question of How come? i think it's purely down to how fast the tooling has been changing lately combined with how few are really doing it. There's a huge push for larger companies to move to K8s and i think they've basically just drowned out the FaaS adopters. Not that it should be like that, or that we at Codeship don't want to change that; it's just how i personally see things.